# Using Orthogonal Projections in Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, projection-matrices

Let $L$ be the line passing through the point $P_1 = (5, 3, −4)$ with direction vector $ d = (−3, −3, −1) $ and let $L_2$ be the line passing through the point $P_2 = (2, 1, 5)$ with the same direction vector.
Find the shortest distance $d$ between these two lines.

Is it possible to use normal projection formula to find this answer? I seem to be missing a step... I would kill for some good tools or strategies to solve these efficiently.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Take a look at [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to learn how to properly typeset mathematical expressions in your posts. Also, these are parallel lines, are'nt? How would you do it in two dimensions?

Comment: @Leigh: see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2213165/find-shortest-distance-between-lines-in-3d

Comment: @Leigh: For parapell lines se here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347604/find-3d-distance-between-two-parallel-lines-in-simple-way

Answer (score 0):

If you know your lines are parallels you can use the formula of the distance between a point and a line which uses ortogonal projections. See David's answer in the bottom of the page here: [Find 3D distance between two parallel lines in simple way](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1347604/find-3d-distance-between-two-parallel-lines-in-simple-way)